# File Output node ignores inputs and exports all render layers

Tags: compositing-nodes

For some reason whatever I add as input in the *File output* node is not exported in the output multilayer exr file, but rather all the render layers are exported.

[image]

[image]

This is the result *exr* file imported into blender, I was expecting 2 layers: ***output 1*** and ***output 2*** not all the render layers.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the file output results were overridden by the *Composite* node, so I deleted the Composite node and changed the file type to *OpenEXR Multilayer* from the node properties rather from the render settings tab. Now it works as expected.

[image]